# migrate TYPO3 Flow project to Neos

Tags: migrate, typo3-flow, neoscms

Still in decision-making if for a new project whether TYPO3 FLOW or TYPO3 NEOS.

What's if I realize as a FLOW project.

Is it possible and when how to migrate to Neos afterwards?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TYPO3 Neos` is a `TYPO3 Flow` project. That means that `TYPO3 Neos` contains of several  `TYPO3 Flow` packages that provide the `TYPO3 Neos` functionality.

That means you can safely start with `TYPO3 Flow` and add the `TYPO3 Neos`packages any time.

Please take a look at the `composer` file to understand this better: https://git.typo3.org/Neos/Distributions/Base.git/blob/HEAD:/composer.json

Therefore, adding the packages `typo3/neos` and `typo3/neos-nodetypes` should do the trick.

Tell your boss that `TYPO3 Flow` is the right decision ;)

---

Actually it is the concept of `TYPO3 Neos` that it sits on top of `TYPO3 Flow` such that it can be added any time a `CMS` functionality is needed.

Enjoy the flow ;-)